# False positives for Block State Dependency vulnerability

Tags: timestamp, randomness, bug, vulnerability

I've been analysing the contract in https://github.com/SoftSec-KAIST/Smartian/blob/main/examples/sol/BD_false.sol, which contains false positives for the bug Block State Dependency (see https://swcregistry.io/docs/SWC-120).
The lines [68](https://github.com/SoftSec-KAIST/Smartian/blob/45430325557db85f32d034b6aca70a4d9cc27d66/examples/sol/BD_false.sol#L68),[71](https://github.com/SoftSec-KAIST/Smartian/blob/45430325557db85f32d034b6aca70a4d9cc27d66/examples/sol/BD_false.sol#L71) and [84](https://github.com/SoftSec-KAIST/Smartian/blob/45430325557db85f32d034b6aca70a4d9cc27d66/examples/sol/BD_false.sol#L84) of the contract seem to have this bug, but they are marked in https://github.com/SoftSec-KAIST/Smartian/blob/main/examples/NOTE.md as false positives.

Can someone please shed lights on why this are false positives and not true positives?

Answer (score 0):

The SWC-120 flags using block parameters like timestamp and number as a week source of randomness. But the contract doesn't use them as source of randomness.

For example line 68 uses `block.timestamp` to determine a range where deposits will be accepted.

```
if (block.timestamp < startTime || block.timestamp >= deadline) throw;
```

Line 70-72 has a bug. `msg.value` is added to `this.balance` before the transaction is executed. The lines are redundant in any case.

```
if (this.balance + msg.value >= capAmount) {
    deadline = block.timestamp;
}
```

Line 84 the function can be only called by the owner, and is used to initialize the correct date range for the deposits.

```
if (block.timestamp >= startTime) throw;
```